# How to run DB requests asynchronously?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

When I run this it lists off the websites in the database one by one with the response code and it takes about 10 seconds to run through a very small list. It should be way faster and isn't running asynchronously but I'm not sure why.

```
import dblogin
import aiohttp
import asyncio
import async_timeout

dbconn = dblogin.connect()
dbcursor = dbconn.cursor(buffered=True)
dbcursor.execute("SELECT thistable FROM adatabase")
website_list = dbcursor.fetchall()

async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(30):
        async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
            await response.read()
            return response.status, url

async def main():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for all_urls in website_list:
            url = all_urls[0]
            resp = await fetch(session, url)
            print(resp, url)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.close()

dbcursor.close()
dbconn.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

[This article](https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html) explains the details. What you need to do is pass each fetch call in a `Future` object, and then pass a list of those to either `asyncio.wait` or `asyncio.gather` depending on your needs.

Your code would look something like this:

```
async def fetch(session, url):
    with async_timeout.timeout(30):
        async with session.get(url, ssl=False) as response:
            await response.read()
            return response.status, url

async def main():
    tasks = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for all_urls in website_list:
            url = all_urls[0]
            task = asyncio.create_task(fetch(session, url))
            tasks.append(task)

        responses = await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.create_task(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

---

Also, are you sure that `loop.close()` call is needed? The docs mention that

> The loop must not be running when this function is called. Any pending callbacks will be discarded.
>
> This method clears all queues and shuts down the executor, but does not wait for the executor to finish.

---

As mentioned in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#creating-tasks) and in the link that @user4815162342 posted, it is better to use the `create_task` method instead of the `ensure_future` method when we know that the argument is a coroutine. Note that this was added in Python 3.7, so previous versions should continue using `ensure_future` instead.

Comment: Please consider [using `create_task` rather than `ensure_future`](https://github.com/python/asyncio/issues/477#issuecomment-268709555) when you know the argument is a coroutine. `ensure_future` is a specialized function designed to be used by combinators such as `gather` to convert arbitrary awaitables into futures.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I didn't know that. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Thanks! That article really helped and I was able to get it working for the most part. It just requires a bit of tweaking to get it to do what I want.