# Django asyncio for saving (big amount of) objects - Nothing saved

Tags: django, database, python-asyncio

I want to fetch categories from a Magento API and display them in a template. In the same time, I want to save them in DB for an ulterior use.

Categories are too many and the render of the template takes more than 30 sec.

I start to learn using **asyncio** but couldn't get my way with it. I surely missed something.

First, my URL leads to the function that retrieves the categories

```
@login_required
def get_categories(request):
    Category.objects.all().delete()
    try:
        cats = fetch_categories()
        tree = cats['children_data']
    except:
        print('erreur : impossible de récupérer les catégories (fetch_categories)')

    asyncio.run(parse_categories(tree))
    return render(request, 'categories/categories_list.html', {'tree': tree})
```

When I get the "categories tree", I send it to

```
async def parse_categories(tree):

    for lvl1 in tree:
        all_tasks = []
        asyncio.create_task(save_cat(lvl1))

        # main products categories (turbo, injectors ...)
        for lvl2 in lvl1['children_data']:
            asyncio.create_task(save_cat(lvl2))

            # sub categories like RENAULT, DACIA
            for lvl3 in lvl2['children_data']:
                asyncio.create_task(save_cat(lvl3))

                for lvl4 in lvl3['children_data']:
                    asyncio.create_task(save_cat(lvl4))

                    for lvl5 in lvl4['children_data']:
                        asyncio.create_task(save_cat(lvl5))
```

My save() function is async. I'm not sure it should be. Before I started using async, it was working.

```
async def save_cat(cat):
    cat_id = cat['id']

    new_cat = Category()
    new_cat.id = cat_id
    new_cat.name = cat.get('name', None)
    new_cat.parent = cat.get('parent_id', None)
    new_cat.url = cat.get('path', None)
    new_cat.is_active = cat.get('is_active', None)
    new_cat.position = cat.get('position', None)
    new_cat.level = cat.get('level', None)
    new_cat.save()
```

When I run, **no error**. The context is well sent to the template and displays well. But no category is saved.

I also tried to make a task list with **asyncio.create_task** in each level and execute the loop at the end of **parse_categories()** like said [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56123945/how-to-run-db-requests-asynchronously), without success.

```
all_tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(save_cat(lvl1)))
[...]
responses = asyncio.gather(*all_tasks, return_exceptions=True)
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(responses)
loop.close()
```

Any clue to solve my case will be welcome

Comment: You create a bunch of tasks but you never await any of them. `parse_categories` completed and the event loop shuts down without waiting for all of your tasks to finish. You need to use `await` and something like `asyncio.gather`.

Comment: I thought creating a list of tasks and use a loop asyncio.gather (like in my 2nd method at bottom) would work. Wouldn't it ? This is what you say I'm not doing.
I transformed `parse_categories`as async function and `await` its call , used again the `loop` + `asyncio.gather` but now I got this message : _The view categories.views.get_categories didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned an unawaited coroutine instead_. You may need to add an 'await' into your view.

Comment: The error message seems due to `@login_required` decorator, visibly not supported by async functions as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64908222/error-your-view-return-an-httpresponse-object-it-returned-an-unawaited-corouti)

Comment: Sorry, missed your second example. You can’t call `run_until_complete` inside a function defined with `async def`. You need to use `await` instead. Also, none of your code is actually asynchronous so based on your examples there’s no value in using asyncio here.

Comment: @dirn : thanks for your time. So maybe I'm not using the good tool to achieve what I wan't to do. My goal was to save objects in background to avoid the user waiting dozen of seconds. Visibly, there is lotsa things I didn't understand. I will revise the subject of asynchronous functions

Comment: Found a working workaround with Celery (that I had already used) in 4 min . When I got more time, I'll come back on asyncio.